# Joining Lists of Different Objects

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have 2 lists of custom types.  They have a common element called ItemID, I want to get all the elements where they exist in one, but not the other.  Does anyone have any ideas?

I basically need the opposite of an inner join, but only want the elements from itemList that aren't in itemCheckoutList or they can be in itemCheckoutList if IsComplete is true.  Here is the inner join I have to get all in both with IsComplete being false:

```
itemList.Join(itemCheckoutList,
         i => i.ItemID,
         ic => ic.ItemID,
         (i, ic) => new { itemList = i, itemCheckoutList = ic }).Where(x => x.itemCheckoutList.IsComplete == false).ToList();
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is what you want.

```
itemList.Where(i => i.IsComplete || 
                    !itemCheckoutList.Any(ic => ic.ItemID == i.ItemID))
```

**EDIT**

Based on your comment I think this is what you want.

```
itemList.Where(i => !itemCheckoutList.Any(ic => ic.ItemID == i.ItemID && 
                                                !ic.IsComplete))
```

**EDIT**

If efficiency is an issue then you'll want to create a lookup for `itemCheckoutList` that you can reuse or just change `itemCheckoutList` to a `Dictionary<int, CheckOutItem>` as CodeCaster suggests.  That can be done like this.

```
// This should preferably be called just once but 
// would need to be called whenever the list changes
var checkOutListLookup = itemCheckoutList.ToLookup(ic => ic.ItemID);

// and this can be called as needed.
var results = itemList.Where(i => !checkOutListLookup.Contains(i.ItemID) ||
                                  checkOutListLookup[i.ItemID].IsComplete);
```

Or if you make it a `Dicionary<int, CheckOutItem>` it would look like this.

```
var results = itemList.Where(i => !checkOutDictionary.ContainsKey(i.ItemID) ||
                                  checkOutDictionary[i.ItemID].IsComplete);
```

Comment: Note that this does a linear search through the second list for every single item in the first.

Comment: @Servy Not every single item.  Just the ones where `IsComplete` is `false`.

Comment: And if that is a problem, OP could create a `Dictionary<ItemID, Item>` for `itemCheckoutList` to do a `.ContainsKey()` on, which is `O(1)`.

Comment: @juharr Sure, honestly he should just have the `Where` first in his original query.  The idea is that you're still doing a linear search on all of the items in the query *that you're actually joining on*.

Comment: thanks, I had to switch it around a bit because IsComplete is a member of itemCheckoutList not itemList but looking at my original question I stupidly put x in there leaving you to guess at where it was coming from.  Thanks for your help its exactly what I needed!!

Comment: @Servy I changed my original query too, I think you're right that was the way to go.

Comment: @mgrenier You still shouldn't be doing this if the data sets aren't trivially small.  Juharrs point doesn't address the core flaw that I pointed out.

Comment: @mgrenier I've updated my answer to include strategies to help if you do have large sets of data and you find that this query is an unacceptable bottle neck to your code.

Comment: Fantastic thanks for everyone who contributed here!  I created a dictionary which will definitely be way more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `GroupJoin`:

```
itemList
    .GroupJoin(itemCheckoutList, item => item.ItemID, itemCheckout => itemCheckout.ItemID, (item, itemCheckouts) => new {item, itemCheckouts})
    .SelectMany(t => t.itemCheckouts.DefaultIfEmpty(), (t, itemCheckout) => new { t.item, itemCheckout })
    .Where(t => t.item.IsComplete || t.itemCheckout == null)
    .Select(t => t.item);
```

or the same written as linq query:

```
var l = from item in itemList
        join itemCheckout in itemCheckoutList on item.ItemID equals itemCheckout.ItemID into gj
        from itemCheckout in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
        where item.IsComplete || itemCheckout == null
        select item;
```